# Python: managing a list of Tasks

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I am trying to create a "schedule". A class that will contain a class "Day" (Monday-Sunday) and each Day will have various "Tasks":
This is the way I am doing it (code below), in this case "day_of_the_week[1]" would be the equivalent of Tuesday. This line gives an error "list index out of range"

```
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self,name,start,end):
        self.name = name
        self.start = start
        self.end = end



class Day(object):
    time_available = []
    check_time = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []
        for i in range(24):
            self.time_available.append(i)
    def add_task(self,name,start,end):
        for i in range(start, end + 1, 1):
            self.check_time.append(i)
        if set(self.check_time).issubset(self.time_available):
            # check if timeslot is available
            for i in range(start, end + 1, 1):
                self.time_available.remove(i)
            del self.check_time[:]
            self.tasks.append(Task(name, start, end))
            print "TRUE"
            return True
        else:
            del self.check_time[:]
            print "FALSE"
            return False

        #check if task can be added





class Schedule(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.day_of_the_week = []
    def add_day(self):
        self.day_of_the_week.append(Day())



schedule = Schedule()
schedule.add_day()
schedule.add_day()
schedule.day_of_the_week[0].add_task("swimming", 11, 13)
schedule.day_of_the_week[0].add_task("swimming", 14, 17)
schedule.day_of_the_week[0].add_task("swimming", 10, 12)
schedule.day_of_the_week[1].add_task("swimming", 10, 12)
schedule.day_of_the_week[1].add_task("swimming", 10, 13)
```

Comment: You're trying to add tasks to a day you never added to the schedule.

Comment: if I "add more days" I found that it looked like the "time_available" would reset. I was checking if day[0] had time available in a specific slot. As is right now the third swimming task wouldn't be inserted. But once I added more days, it would insert. Are my variables declared correctly in "Day"?

Comment: They don't look right. `time_available` and `check_time` are declared as class variables instead of instance variables for some reason.

Comment: can you give an example of how I would make them instance variables?

Comment: Same thing you did with `self.tasks`.

Comment: LOL you da real MVP. it works!

Answer (score 0):

You just defined the first element with

```
schedule.add_day()
```

just one element is added.
The first element has the index "0".
That's why these lines don't cause errors:

```
schedule.day_of_the_week[0].add_task("swimming", 11, 13)
schedule.day_of_the_week[0].add_task("swimming", 14, 17)
schedule.day_of_the_week[0].add_task("swimming", 10, 12)
```

But then you try to access the second entry with the index "1", but there's just one.